# Find the lowest value of all the high values

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write haskell function that takes list of lists and find the lowest value of all the high values.

So the function takes the list [[1,1,3],[2,5],[1]] and return 1 because its the lowest of 3,5,1.

What haskell function can I use?

Comment: Can you please define "high values" a bit more?

Comment: This is nothing i am going to hand in. I am preparing myself before exam in programming lanugage course. So I'm trying to solve as many problems as I can and could not figure this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using list comprehension :

```
maxi xxs = minimum [ maximum a | a <- xxs]
```

(I'm a beginner in Haskell ... and coding. It's the first time that I figure it out an answer arround here. So, Gratzz to me!! :P  )

Answer (score 4):

Data.List contains useful functions,

```
:browse Data.List
```

in ghci.

(Looks a lot like homework, so...)

Answer (score 2):

Think "step by step": First you need find all maximums of the individual lists, e.g.:

```
map maximum [[1,1,3],[2,5],[1]]
--[3,5,1]
```

Then you need the minimum of this list. So one solution would be:

```
minOfMax xs = minimum (map maximum xs)
```

Of course you can also write your own recursive solution, or use a fold:

```
minOfMax (x:xs) = foldl f (maximum x) xs where 
    f a bs = min a (maximum bs)
```